# SASS in .net MVC5 with sassandcoffee install

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, sass

so I am working on a MVC 5 project and im wanting to uses SASS (SCSS) styles, iv installed coffeeandsass from the nuget package manager

Iv started by setting some color's as variables

```
    $Blue: #0075be;
    $LightBlue: #66c7e6;
    $Grey: #55575e;
    $Yellow: #ffc000;
    $Pinkish: #e96252;
    $Green: #47b988;
    $DarkGreen: #223e48;
    $Purple: #481069;
    $OffWhite: #f4f2e8;
    $OffGrey: #8b9a91;

.Pinkish {
    background-color: $Pinkish;
}
```

and then adding this file to the bundles reference

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/CSS/index.scss",                    
                  "~/Content/Site.css"));
```

but the variables are not taking place,

references installed are, IronRuby, IronRuby.Libraries, IronRuby.Libraries.Yaml, sassand coffee.aspnet, core javascript and ruby

thanks in advance

Comment: Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.is show in chrome debug

Answer (score 0):

This is because the bundler can not compile `SCSS`files, hence it is failing.  The easiest thing to do is to use [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com) to compile the `SCSS` files for you.  Then you can just bundle the generated `CSS` files.

One of the great things about using Web Essentials is that it compiles using LibSass, which node based, so you do not have to have Ruby installed on your machine.

Comment: I tried using web essentials, it wasnt working, turns out there was a bug is sassy studio at the time